# From how deep in the mantle has any rock ever been brought to the surface? Have scientists found anything they believe originated in the outer core?

Tags: geology, geophysics, structural-geology, mantle, geologic-layers

I wonder if this is even possible to know....

Do geophysicists and geologists have even a 'theoretical' idea about how deep Earth's churning of its layers goes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_convection, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcanism, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magmatism as a start. These are two poor questions that can't have good answers without prior knowledge.

Comment: The deepest we've dug is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole, which is 12.2km deep, or 0.42% of the way to the outer core. (Note that this doesn't actually answer any of your questions)

Comment: I've found some [rock that originated in the outer core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_the_Moon), possibly even the inner core

Answer (score 5):

Diamond is stable at high temperatures only under very high pressures. Mineral inclusions in a diamond, and the rocks in which a diamond are embedded, can offer further clues as to the depth from which the diamond came.

The [Wikipedia article on diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond#Geology) claims "A smaller fraction of diamonds (about 150 have been studied) come from depths of 330–660 km, a region that includes the transition zone. They formed in eclogite but are distinguished from diamonds of shallower origin by inclusions of majorite (a form of garnet with excess silicon). A similar proportion of diamonds comes from the **lower mantle at depths between 660 and 800 km.** [20]" (my emphasis)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the best estimate is "upper mantle" from [mantle xenoliths](https://earthandsolarsystem.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/mantle-xenoliths-a-window-into-the-interior-of-the-earth/) but that's not terribly specific. I am not sure if knowing more than that is possible right now.

Comment: The term is used for a wide range of magmatic compositions, but often times with magma that came a long way through continental crust. A mid ocean ridge basalt otoh regularly originates in the upper mantle. So there is so much more to it.